# Why does log using file con manager (with usage type as `Create file`) append the data?

Tags: ssis

I have configured logging in SSIS using the file connection manager.

In the file con mgr settings I have selected the usage type as `Create file`. The filename is dynamically derived based on current date. So today's log file will be: `LOG_20220330.txt`

Every time the SSIS runs, the logs get appended to this file. This is fine but I am trying to understand why this happens because I was expecting this behavior had I selected the `Existing file` option on the usage type.

Why is it appending the logs even when I selected the usage type as `Create file`?